# What is the proper way for defining javascript variables in different cshtml files which have a common js file?

Tags: javascript, html, asp.net-mvc

There is a cshtml file in which we store Model values in the javascript variables like this.

```
@model sampleVM;
<script>
var x = "@Model.x";
var y = "@Model.y";
</script>
<script src="sample.js"></script>
```

In sample.js and in document.ready, the code looks like this.

```
docready
{
var z = 5;
alert(x+y+z);
}
```

Does it affect the script parsing time because we have defined the variables in the multiple cshtml files like above? Is there any better way to it?

Comment: You can encapsulate it. `var x = (function() {return "@Model.x"; })()`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"Better way of doing it" is not really objective, but here is my take:
I'd get rid of the inline scripts in the cshtml altogether. Why? If you want to parse, lint or transpile or javascript code, using rollup, webpack or whatever the Js-framework of the day currently is, you'll have a hard time doing that, when your javascript code is hidden in cshtml file. Your example is rather small, but projects grow in complexity over time and since your js is already mixed with razor syntax, you could as well add the new requirements there surely? And then you'll end up with javascript code fragmented all over your project in js and cshtml files. So: to me it is a code smell.

What I would do is the following: 
Use your model in your markup:

```
<input type="hidden" name="xValue" id="xValue" value="@Model.x" />
<input type="hidden" name="yValue" id="yValue" value="@Model.y" />
```

And call it from your sample.js file:

```
$('document').ready(function(){
   var x = $('#xValue').val();
   var y = $('#yValue').val();
   //... do stuff with it
});
```

Your cshtml file would then simply reference that file:

```
@section scripts {
    <script src="~/sample.js"></script>
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can set x, y as window variable and you can use in sample.js file

```
@model sampleVM;
<script>
window.x = "@Model.x";
window.y = "@Model.y";
</script>
```